# Perform multiple functions on each object in an array and redirect the results to a file

Tags: arrays, linux, function, shell, loops

**How to perform multiple functions on each object in an array and output the results to a file?**

Heres my array, its the value of a command, that command lists all text files in the current directory:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

declare -a FILES
FILES=( $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.txt") )
```

As you can see below, it works:

```sh
# Print the full array:
echo "${FILES[@]}"

 ./1.txt ./2.txt ./3.txt

# Print the number of objects in the array:
echo "${#FILES[@]}"

3

# Loop through each object in the array and print its name:
for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "$file"
done

./1.txt
./2.txt
./3.txt
```

For each object in the array I need to perform three functions:

```sh
# Use grep to return a whole line:
GREP="$(cat "$file" | grep 'String_A')"
```

```sh
# Use awk to return part of a line only  (the second column, after the first colon)
AWK="$(cat "$file" | awk -F: '/String_B/ {print $2; exit}')"
```

```sh
# Use sed to return all lines from C to E  (C + D + E)
SED="$(cat "$file" | sed -nE '/String_C/,/String_E/p')"
```

For this, a "for loop":

```sh
for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
echo "$GREP : $AWK : $SED"
done

File_1_Grep_String_A : File_1_Awk_String_B : File_1_Sed_String_C
File_1_Sed_String_D
File_1_Sed_String_E
File_3_Grep_String_A : File_3_Awk_String_B : File_3_Sed_String_C
File_3_Sed_String_D
File_3_Sed_String_E
File_2_Grep_String_A : File_2_Awk_String_B : File_2_Sed_String_C
File_2_Sed_String_D
File_2_Sed_String_E
```

This is all the that I require, but I need this info written to a file called `results`,
the problem is, when I redirect this output to a file, only the first object in the array is parsed:

```sh
for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "$GREP : $AWK : $SED" > Some_File
done

cat Some_File

File_2_Grep_String_A : File_2_Awk_String_B : File_2_Sed_String_C
File_2_Sed_String_D
File_2_Sed_String_E
```

### Summary:

The command works correctly when it outputs to stdout but not when redirected to a file.

I have found similar questions here on stackoverflow (performing functions on arrays) but none redirect output to a file.

I find this quite weird, I have never had a command output to stdout fine but unable to get that in text elsewhere.

Whilst I'm new here, my last couple questions wasnt recieved well by some members as I was too brief,
so I think this time I have fully explained and shown the output step-by-step.

Also, to save you the burden of making an identical test environment and copy/paste'ing all of this,
I put it up on github for you to clone, hopefully this helps.

Again, to ease things, in there you will find two scripts,
the main one in question, called `script.sh` (this is the one that needs fixing, its clean/uncommented)
but I also included one called `tests.sh`, this is basically all the steps I have taken,
it contains alot of comments that will further help you understand better than I can explain here.

To be honest, I would **definately** have a quick look at that first,
its also safe to execute (it contains all the working bits I have shown above, like printing the array),
this saves you typing out commands to test the array etc.

Thank you in advance! I hope I've done better this time?!?

`git clone https://github.com/5c0tt-b0t/stackoverflow_test`

Test script output:

```sh
########## TESTS: ##########                               
FULL ARRAY:
./1.txt ./3.txt ./2.txt

COUNT:
3
                                                          
OBJECTS:
./1.txt
                                                           
 OBJECTS:
./3.txt

OBJECTS:                                                   
./2.txt
                                                    
########## INFO THAT I NEED: ##########
File_1_Grep_String_A : File_1_Awk_String_B : File_1_Sed_String_C
File_1_Sed_String_D
File_1_Sed_String_E
File_3_Grep_String_A : File_3_Awk_String_B : File_3_Sed_String_C
File_3_Sed_String_D
File_3_Sed_String_E
File_2_Grep_String_A : File_2_Awk_String_B : File_2_Sed_String_C
File_2_Sed_String_D
File_2_Sed_String_E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the output of the whole loop:

```sh
for file in "${FILES[@]}"
do
  echo "$GREP : $AWK : $SED"
done > Some_File
```

Also, use `#!/bin/bash` when using bashisms like arrays, `/bin/sh` doesn't necessarily support arrays.

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly! I guess I just found one of the shells "quirks", looking at it, it still seems my efforts should work as I expected, instead of changing the command because I am redirecting to a file instead of stdout. I learned something new today, thanks for teaching me it! just accepted this as my answer and a +1 too! Thanks @choroba

Comment: Your version overwrites the file in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Of course it does! if it had '>>' instead, it would work, but I have to remember it will always append, in my case I want to update the list, but simply placing a command up the top of the script that wipes the list first would solve that, or deleting and touching it again. Thanks for teaching me twice! another +1 from me!